# How to select data from last three months from the latest date in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My data looks like :

```
ID Date 
1 07/03/2020
2 07/02/2020
3 07/05/2020
4 07/10/2020
1 03/03/2020
2 03/04/2020
```

I want for each ID I get the latest date and the 90 days prior date. I am not able to use max date and group by for this.

Comment: Please define the "90 days prior date".

Comment: please clarify 1)what is the data type of Date column? is it date or string? 2) provide example of expected output

Answer (score 0):

If you want all data within three months of the latest date, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(date) over (partition by id) as max_date
      from t
     ) t
where date >= date_add(max_day, interval -90 day)
```